# Create 2D array in C++ from dimension given in constructor of a class

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to build a method inside a class that populates a matrix.

```
class my_function{

public:

    my_function(double _x
        , double _y
        , int_N) {

        x = _x;
        y = _y;
        N= _N;
        
    }

       void Make_matrix() {
        vector<vector<double>> my_matrix(N+1, vector<double>(N+1));
 
        for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                my_matrix[i][j] = x*y;
                cout << my_matrix[i][j] << endl;
            }
        }
       
    }

public:
    double x;
    double y;
    int N;
};
```

However, this code throws several errors:

```
1.l-value specifies const object 
2.'std::vector<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>>,std::allocator<std::vector<double,std::allocator<double>>>>::vector(const unsigned int,const _Alloc &)': cannot convert argument 2 from'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>>' to 'const _Alloc &' 
3.'my_function::N':  an object of const-qualified type must be initialized
```

Do you know how I can actually find a way to initialize and populate this 2D vector from the N specified in the constructor? Error 1 seems to be referring to N, which I am not sure whether requires to be of type const as it defines the dimensions of the 2D vector. I am open for any suggestion!
Thank you!

I tried defining N in different ways however it did not really work...
Just want to say that I have just started using c++ in visual studio for windows.

Comment: `Make_matrix()` promised to return 1 single double value but broke that promise making your entire program invalid.

Comment: Your other errors are not reproducible: [https://ideone.com/L2pMz0](https://ideone.com/L2pMz0) The code compiles after adding the 2 missing includes.

Comment: Why does the constructor take a `double _N` and not an `int _N`?

Comment: @joergbrech taking an `int` to indicate the size of the array wouldn't be proper either since you can't have a negative size array which both the `double` and `int` would signify. Best to use`size_t` instead.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious very true. @kyara, you would also have to change the member `int N` to `size_t N`.

Comment: I overlooked that. I will edit those two points.  Thanks!